# How to stop Ajax interval function while loading new content to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this AJAX interval function that I'm using to fill my page with content. (There's just one page in the website also loaded with script below)

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../cors.php?url=asd.com',
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 3000,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (a) {
            var strHtml = '';
            $.each(a.scores, function (key, value) {
                strHtml += ' <span class="span">' + value.image + '</span><br />';
            });
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = strHtml;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    }); 
}, 5000, true);
```

Once I load the new content to my page with this AJAX script below script is still working in the background and I'm getting `innerHtml` error messages.

```
function loadPage(url) {
    url = url.replace('#gg', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'content_loader.php',
        data: 'page=' + url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (msg) {
            if (parseInt(msg) !== 0) {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How can I stop the browser requesting `../cors.php?url=asd.com` after new content loaded by the script below from `content_loader.php`? I would like to stop the function including data JavaScript to `content_loader.php` (and running JS while AJAX POST and getting new content).

Comment: Use `clearInterval(myInterval)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop JavaScript execution when Ajax loads new content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087523/how-to-stop-javascript-execution-when-ajax-loads-new-content)

Comment: Where is `loadPage` called?